# Swift: Constrained extension on Dictionary by Element

Tags: ios, swift

I want to create an extension on Dictionary that only affects dictionaries with type [String:AnyObject], which is the data type returned from parsed JSON dictionaries. Here's how I set it up:

```
typealias JSONDictionary = [String : AnyObject]
extension Dictionary where Element:JSONDictionary {
    // Some extra methods that are only valid for this type of dictionary.
}
```

Xcode is generating an error on `Element`, saying it's an undeclared type. However, the *first line* of the definition of Dictionary is a typealias declaring Element. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`Element` is a tuple:

```
typealias Element = (Key, Value)
```

That cannot match the type you're trying to compare it to (a Dictionary). You can't even say something like `where Element:(String, AnyObject)` because tuples don't subtype that way. For example, consider:

```
var x: (CustomStringConvertible, CustomStringConvertible) = (1,1)
var y: (Int, Int) = (1,1)
x = y // Cannot express tuple conversion '(Int, Int)' to ('CustomStringConvertible', 'CustomStringConvertible')
```

Compare:

```
var x1:CustomStringConvertible = 1
var y1:Int = 1
x1 = y1 // No problem
```

I suspect you get "undeclared type" is because `Element` is no longer an unbound type parameter, it's a bound type parameter. `Dictionary` is conforming to `SequenceType` here. So you can't parameterize on it (at least not in one step; you have to chase it through another layer of type parameters to discover it's "ultimately" unbound). That seems a bad error message, but I suspect it bubbles out of "undeclared type out of the list of types that could possibly be used here." I think that's worth opening a radar on for a better error message.

Instead, I think you mean this:

```
extension Dictionary where Key: String, Value: AnyObject { }
```

---

EDIT for Swift 2:

This is no longer legal Swift. You can only constrain based on protocols. The equivalent code would be:

```
protocol JSONKey {
    func toString() -> String
}
extension String: JSONKey {
    func toString() -> String { return self }
}

extension Dictionary where Key: JSONKey, Value: AnyObject { ... }
```

Comment: I appreciate your going the extra mile to explain the problem and solution so eloquently!

Comment: I get `<unknown>:0: error: type 'Key' constrained to non-protocol type 'String'`

Comment: @fpg1503 Swift has changed a lot since then. I've updated the answer

Comment: I'd probably use `StringLiteralConvertible` instead of creating a useless protocol just to fool the compiler, though.

Comment: @fpg1503 I'm not fooling the compiler there. I'm making a protocol of things I want to support. StringLiteralConvertible doesn't have a "get the string back out" method as I recall so I don't think it would work.

Comment: Yeah, it's one way only :/ I ended up renaming `JSONKey` to `StringConvertible` so it can be useful somewhere else.